# How do I prevent emacs C/C++ mode from autocorrecting?

Tags: c++, c, emacs

If I run "emacs -q" (prevents loading of user config, so I know it's not a problem with my setup) and open an empty buffer called foo.C and type:

```
case elSE:
```

And then hit ':', emacs insists on changing "elSE" to "Else". I have no idea *why* it's doing this; I assume it thinks I'm misspelling the "else" keyword, except it's capitalizing it so I really have no idea what's going on. How do I disable this behavior?

This is with Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: You misspelt "misspelling" :P

Comment: No idea what you're talking about ;) ;) ;)

Comment: [\*ahem\**youcanthide*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8843695/revisions)

Comment: Wait, why did you edit your post to make it wrong again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also happens for me on Emacs 24; it seems to be caused by abbrev-mode - try `M-x abbrev-mode` to disable it.